# Proving one to one property of a function

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

My question reads:

> Prove that if the real-valued function $f$ is increasing (or decreasing), then $f$ is one-to-one.

Here is my proof after meeting with my professor.

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be increasing (or decreasing) on $\Bbb{R}$

Let $x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ s.t. $x_1 \neq x_2$ then we need to show $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$.
Then we have two cases, where either  $x_1<x_2$ or $x_1>x_2$

**Case 1:** $x_1 < x_2$

Then $f(x_1)< f(x_2)$ meaning $f$ is increasing

**Case 2:** $x_1 > x_2$

Then $f(x_1)< f(x_2)$ meaning $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Is your  increasing "strictly  increasing" ?

Comment: The question does not specify

Comment: The statement is only true if the function is *strictly* monotonic.

Comment: Then it is strictly increasing or deceeasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not prove why $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$.

As you said, fix $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and you have two cases, either $x<y$ or $x>y$.

If $f$ is increasing, then in the first case, $f(x) < f(y)$ and in the second case, $f(x) > f(y)$, but either way $f(x) \ne f(y)$.

If $f$ is decreasing, then in the first case, $f(x) > f(y)$ and in the second case, $f(x) < f(y)$, but either way $f(x) \ne f(y)$.

So no matter if $f$ increasing or decreasing, $x \ne y \implies f(x) \ne f(y)$, and so $f$ must be one-to-one.

**UPDATE** Note this assumes that when you write *increasing* or *decreasing*, the intent is **strictly** *increasing* or **strictly** *decreasing*.

Comment: Then I need to use increasing and decreasing in both cases?

Comment: @Sam yes. You must prove that $f$ is 1-1 whether it is increasing or decreasing -- any monotone function should do

Comment: The I need to use the fact that f is increasing or decreasing in both cases?

Comment: @Sam yes, correct

Comment: But if we assume x < y then how would be get a decreasing case in that case

Comment: Then is my proof wrong?

Comment: I am not too sure if what I have is incomplete?

Comment: @Sam yes, your proof is incorrect. To answer your previous question, if $x<y$ and $f$ is decreasing, you must have $f(x) > f(x)$ which means $f(x) \ne f(y)$...